# On iOS, UnityWebRequest download stops when app goes to background

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine, assetbundle, unitywebrequest

I use UnityWebRequestAssetBundle.GetAssetBundle to download asset bundles located on a remote server. While everything works as expected on Android, the download stops on iOS when minimizing the app (or when the device goes to sleep).

When I foreground the app again, XCode shows the following logs:

```
-> applicationWillResignActive()
-> applicationDidEnterBackground()
2020-03-08 08:37:51.571235+0100 app[3852:2943256] Can't end BackgroundTask: no background task exists with identifier 1 (0x1), or it may have already been ended. Break in UIApplicationEndBackgroundTaskError() to debug.
-> applicationWillEnterForeground()
2020-03-08 08:37:55.169337+0100 app[3852:2943564] [] nw_read_request_report [C4] Receive failed with error "Software caused connection abort"
2020-03-08 08:37:55.194339+0100 app[3852:2943564] Task <015CA857-5213-4905-8F1B-4A0E3DA330DE>.<5> HTTP load failed, 350/5095859 bytes (error code: -1005 [1:53])
2020-03-08 08:37:55.195303+0100 app[3852:2943564] Task <446A65DA-5ACF-493C-AE8F-B746364F4A9E>.<6> HTTP load failed, 693/0 bytes (error code: -1005 [1:53])
2020-03-08 08:37:55.197007+0100 app[3852:2943431] Task <015CA857-5213-4905-8F1B-4A0E3DA330DE>.<5> finished with error [-1005] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The network connection was lost." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=53, NSUnderlyingError=0x2800ced00 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1005 "(null)" UserInfo={NSErrorPeerAddressKey=<CFData 0x282ca0be0 [0x1e218bcf0]>{length = 16, capacity = 16, bytes = 0x10021f40c0a801300000000000000000}, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=53, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}}, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <015CA857-5213-4905-8F1B-4A0E3DA330DE>.<5>, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
"LocalDataTask <015CA857-5213-4905-8F1B-4A0E3DA330DE>.<5>"
), NSLocalizedDescription=The network connection was lost., NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://192.168.1.48:8000/Mobile/dlc1, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://192.168.1.48:8000/Mobile/dlc1, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}
```

C# code:

```
public static AssetBundleDownloadProgress DownloadBundle (string bundleName, bool forImmediateLoad, DownloadBundleFinishedDelegate finished, DownloadBundleErrorDelegate error)
 {
     UnityWebRequest wr;

     if (HashDictionaryRemote.ContainsKey(bundleName))
     {
         uint crc = CRCDictionaryRemote[bundleName];
         Hash128 hash = HashDictionaryRemote[bundleName];

         wr = UnityWebRequestAssetBundle.GetAssetBundle (SERVER_URL + bundleName, hash, crc);
     }
     else
     {
         wr = UnityWebRequestAssetBundle.GetAssetBundle (SERVER_URL + bundleName);
     }

     wr.disposeDownloadHandlerOnDispose = true;
     wr.SetRequestHeader ("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
     wr.SetRequestHeader ("Pragma", "no-cache");
     wr.SetRequestHeader ("Expires", "0");

     AssetBundleDownloadProgress progress = new AssetBundleDownloadProgress(wr);

     Instance.StartCoroutine(DownloadBundleCoroutine (wr, forImmediateLoad, progress, bundleName, finished, error));

     return progress;
 }

 private static IEnumerator DownloadBundleCoroutine (UnityWebRequest wr, bool forImmediateLoad, AssetBundleDownloadProgress progress, string bundleName, DownloadBundleFinishedDelegate finished, DownloadBundleErrorDelegate error)
 {
     yield return wr.SendWebRequest();

     if (wr.isNetworkError) 
     {
         error (wr.error);
     } 
     else
     {
         AssetBundle bundle = ((DownloadHandlerAssetBundle)wr.downloadHandler).assetBundle;

         if (bundle == null) 
         {
             error.Invoke($"Error loading bundle {bundleName}, probably another bundle with same files is already loaded.");
         } 
         else
         {
             finished.Invoke(bundle, progress);

             if(!forImmediateLoad)
                 bundle.Unload(true);
         }
     }
 }
```

I use Unity 2019.2

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Generally, IOS make application stop when it goes background so you should make application run when it goes background.

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/Unity-Technologies/iosnativecodesamples/src/ae6a0a2c02363d35f954d244a6eec91c0e0bf194/NativeIntegration/BackgroundTasks/BackgroundFetch/?at=5.0-dev

It helps

Comment: @BrianChoi I'm pretty sure I have seen other iOS apps downloading things in the background. Are you sure about this?

Comment: Also as far as I understand, the link you provided is about Background fetch which is different from what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, it is not possible to download stuff in the background on iOS using regular code. UnityWebRequest is backed [NSURLSession’s dataTaskWithRequest](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlsession). These cannot run in the background. What can be used instead is certain variants of [NSURLSessionTask](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlsessiontask?language=objc). Apps that download assets in the background do so using background fetch, as Brian Choi mentioned in the comments, which uses these NSURLSessionTasks. They write directly to disk, in which case the download is handed over to the OS to complete.

The download can be actively monitored while your app is in the foreground, and it will continue to run in the background, although its priority will be managed by the OS based on network, battery, thermal and other running app conditions of the device.

Unity provides a background downloader package for this very purpose.

https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/BackgroundDownload

In order to load an asset bundle using this, you will have to download to the application's persistentDataPath and then use AssetBundle.LoadFromFile() to actually load the asset bundle.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. Really interesting stuff. I didn't know about that package.